# Unable to Set Startup Form in Visual Studio 2012 (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Okay, in Visual Studio 2012 I have a VB.NET project with originally two forms. Form1 was originally set as the startup form and then obsoleted. Form2 is a nearly identical form that has all of the new desirable functionality.

In my project's settings, Form2 doesn't appear as an available option for Startup Form. (Though it is a normally-created form that inherits Form) After some "troubleshooting," Form1 has been deleted, resulting in the the "Enable Application Framework" option being disabled and no Startup Object being available. When I select anything from the Startup Object drop-down, either Sub Main or Form2, I have an error message stating either "Sub Main not found in Solution" or "Form2 is a type in Solution and cannot be used as an expression" respectively. If I try to enable "Enable Application Framework," I receive an error popup stating "Startup object must be a form when 'Enable application framework' is checked." And Application.Designer.vb is empty.

Some things I've tried:

- Clean and Rebuild Solution
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Temporarily deleting Form1 (it's still excluded from project)
- Added a new form, per Neolisk's advice. It appeared in the available objects. I selected it and turned on application framework. From here, I copied the initialization code from Form2's designer code into Form3's. All was alright. Then, I copied Form2's main code into Form3. Now, "Form3 is a type in Solution and cannot be used as an expression" appears in my error list.

With that said, my question is how can I get Visual Studio to recognize my form as a form and set Form2 as the startup object?

Comment: Try adding a new form, see if it appears in the list. Try opening your solution in VS 2013, see if works there. If you don't have the full one, get Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `InitializeComponent()` in `new()` function in form2

Comment: Yeah, @Fathy, I think the issue was the duplicate constructor not having `InitializeComponent()` in it. I deleted the empty constructor and it worked. I think your response hits the issue more accurately than my own.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The issue was an overload of the form's constructor taking a form as a parameter. Since this was the only constructor in the file, I guess it caused confusion. Commented that out and all was right with the world again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have a different class name from the form file name.

Check if the class name is listed.